# Display context menu over HERE map

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

Using HERE maps, I would like to display a context menu on right-click (or long-touch).

The developers guide lists the [valid mouse/touch events](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/events.html) as:

- pointerdown
- pointerup
- pointermove
- pointerenter
- pointerleave
- pointercancel
- dragstart
- drag
- dragend
- tap
- dbltap

which implies I have to look into checking buttons on `tap` event but the API documentation also describes a [ContextMenuEvent](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-mapevents-contextmenuevent.html) object, stating:

> ContextMenuEvent should be fired, when a user right-clicks or longpresses on a map object.

Which of the events listed above constitutes a "right-click" or "longpress" event, receiving this `ContextMenuEvent` object?

There is a functioning example of a Context Menu on top of a HERE map [here](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/public/api-for-js/context-menu/context-menu.html), but there is no mention of this in the current documentation and it appears to be using an older version of the API.  Has the ability to produce context menus been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a whim I tried attaching to the event type `contextmenu` and it WORKED!  Apparently this is just missing from their documentation.

- contextmenu

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the list is out of sync with the API reference: https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-mapevents-mapevents.html

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative way to handle right-clicks if you are already listening for a "tap" event. In the `originalEvent` property on the tap event object, HERE Maps adds a `which` property to the PointerEvent object, which seems to indicate which button was used to fire the event. This value is `1` for left-clicks, `2` for middle-clicks and `3` for right-clicks.

With this in mind, you can modify your tap event to handle different mouse buttons by doing something similar to the below:

```
map.addEventListener("tap", function (evt) {
    switch (evt.originalEvent.which) {
        case 1: // Left-click
            handleLeftClick(evt);
            break;
        case 3: // Right-click
            handleRightClick(evt);
            break;
        default:
            // Do something else for other buttons, if you want
            break;
    }
});
```